# I've got what appears to be valid jQuery for adding a class to a div based on scroll position, but it's not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've got the following jQuery at the bottom of my site:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(),
            scroll_height = $(window).height(), 
            bkgd = $('.background-image');
        if (scroll_top > scroll_height) {      
            $(bkgd).addClass('blur');   
        } else {      
            $(bkgd).removeClass('blur');
        }
    });
});
```

But nothing happens when I scroll - no class added to the .background-image div.

(I'm a jQuery noob, apologies in advance if this is an obvious/stupid question.)

Comment: you have a spelling mistake `$(bkgd).removeClass('blur');`

Comment: otherwise its fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vEde6/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solved with a typo fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable names don't match up, first it's `bkgd`, then it's `bgkd` ?

Fixing that makes it work for me ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(),
            scroll_height = $(window).height(), 
            bkgd = $('.background-image');
        if (scroll_top > scroll_height) {      
            bkgd.addClass('blur');   
        } else {      
            bkgd.removeClass('blur');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UzhwP/)

As a sidenote, you can shorten that to:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        $('.background-image').toggleClass('blur', $(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height());
    });
});
```